# Trouble connecting to wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

I've always had trouble connecting to a wifi network in my building - but nobody else has any trouble. I've contacted the administrator, but they insist that it's a problem that is specific to me. Here are the details:

- The network is password protected. After connecting to the network, there is a landing page where I need to accept the Terms & Conditions before using the internet.
- It seems that my main problem is trying to load this page. Quite often, it times out and doesn't pop up at all.
- If I restart my computer enough times, "forget" the network, spoof my MAC address, etc. it eventually starts working - but only after fiddling around for 20 minutes.
- The network itself is very fast once I connect. The problem is establishing the connection to begin with. Sometimes I will spend 20 minutes trying to connect, then the landing page pops up, and suddenly I am on a blazingly fast network.
- I'm using Mac OS X. One thing I noticed is that even though I use Google Chrome, the login page opens up in a Safari window. Sometimes, if I clear my history in Safari and bang my keyboard enough times, then I can get the login page to open. However, this isn't a very reliable solution.
- When I *can* access the landing page, I have copied the URL and tried to figure out a shortcut to the login page. Here is how the URL is formatted:

https://mgm-cc[NUMBERS].ccb.cloudwifi.com/portalb/[RANDOM]/[RANDOM]/active/?res=clickthrough_validated&challenge=[RANDOM]&service_id=&login_url=[LOGIN_URL]&logoff_url=[LOGOFF_URL]&ap_id=[MAC_ADDRESS]&uamip=[IP_ADDRESS]&uamport=[PORT]&ap_ssid=[WIFI_NAME]&client_mac=[MAC_ADDRESS]&blackout_time=0&failure_count=0&redirect_type=1&gate_state_to_portal=1&userurl=[URL]&conf_hash=[RANDOM]&login_timeout=86400&home_page=%27%27&challenge_timeout=416

I have tried going directly to the "LOGIN_URL", but this gives an invalid login. Also, when I try connecting, it times out while connecting to "cloudwifi".

---

If anyone can help at all, I would really appreciate it. I am using Mac OSX Sierra 10.12.6. The laptop is a Macbook Pro Retina 15 inch Late 2013 model. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried removing the DNS entries dolled out by the DHCP server and adding the Google DNS entries manually? Use 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4.

Comment: Try using http://neverssl.com/ - read the link to see why and how it works.

Comment: I've run into this a couple of times. The simplest thing I've found that works is:  Once you get connected, do a tracert to any web site. The first IP address in the results should be the router/access point you'll need to log into. Write that down. Next time you have trouble logging in, type http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (where the xx's represent the IP address you wrote down) into the browser's address bar. With luck that'll get you to the login page.